# Variable assignment withing .env file

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

I have one .env file , that looks like :

```
NODE_ENV = local
PORT = 4220
BASE_URL = "http://198.**.**.**:4220/"

PROFILE_UPLOAD = http://198.**.**.**:4220/uploads/profile/
POST_UPLOAD = http://198.**.**.**:4220/uploads/discussion/
COMPANY_UPLOAD = http://198.**.**.**:4220/uploads/company/
ITEM_UPLOAD  = http://198.**.**.**/uploads/item/
GROUP_UPLOAD  = http://198.**.**.**/uploads/group/
```

I want to do something like this :

```
NODE_ENV = local
IP = 198.**.**.**
PORT = 5000
BASE_URL = http://$IP:$PORT/

PROFILE_UPLOAD = $BASE_URL/uploads/profile/
POST_UPLOAD = $BASE_URL/uploads/discussion/
COMPANY_UPLOAD = $BASE_URL/uploads/company/
ITEM_UPLOAD  = $BASE_URL/uploads/item/
GROUP_UPLOAD  = $BASE_URL/uploads/group/
```

Expected result of `BASE_URL` is `http://198.**.**.**:4220/`

I have tried many few syntax but not getting computed values

Tried Syntax : `"${IP}"` ,  `${IP}` ,  `$IP`

I have used **[dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)** package , for accessing env variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[dotenv-expand](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv-expand) was built on top of dotenv to solve this specific problem

Answer (score 21):

[dotenv-expand](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-expand) is the solutions as @maxbeatty answered , Here are the steps to follow

> Steps :

**First Install :**

```
npm install dotenv --save
npm install dotenv-expand --save
```

**Then Change .env file like :**

```
NODE_ENV = local
PORT = 4220
IP = 192.***.**.**
BASE_URL = http://${IP}:${PORT}/

PROFILE_UPLOAD = ${BASE_URL}/uploads/profile/
POST_UPLOAD = ${BASE_URL}/uploads/discussion/
COMPANY_UPLOAD = ${BASE_URL}/uploads/company/
ITEM_UPLOAD  = ${BASE_URL}/uploads/item/
GROUP_UPLOAD  = ${BASE_URL}/uploads/group/
```

**Last Step :**

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var dotenvExpand = require('dotenv-expand');

var myEnv = dotenv.config();
dotenvExpand(myEnv);

process.env.PROFILE_UPLOAD; // to access the .env variable
```

OR (Shorter way)

```
require('dotenv-expand')(require('dotenv').config()); // in just single line
process.env.PROFILE_UPLOAD; // to access the .env variable
```

Comment: It was changed to:
``var dotenv = require('dotenv')
var dotenvExpand = require('dotenv-expand')

var myEnv = dotenv.config()
dotenvExpand.expand(myEnv)``

Answer (score 3):

As already stated you can't assign variables in .env files. You could move your *_UPLOAD files to a `config.js file` and check that into .gitignore , then you could do

```
//config.js

const BASE_URL = `http://${process.env.IP}:${process.env.PORT}/`

module.exports = {
 PROFILE_UPLOAD: BASE_URL+"uploads/profile/",
 POST_UPLOAD: BASE_URL+"uploads/discussion/",
 ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately `dotenv` can't combine variables. Check [this issue](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/78) to see more and find a solution for your project.